# Primefaces selectManyCheckbox layout from top to bottom in columns

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces, orientation, selectmanycheckbox

Task:  There is a panel, with selectMany checkboxes, having 5 columns. The values of selectboxes are ordered by ascending, but they appear from left to right in columns instead of top to bottom.

Using: Primefaces 
Code:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="chkbx" value=.. layout="grid" columns="5">
<p:selectItems value=.. itemValue=".." itemLabel=".."/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Current screen:

```
[] a    [] b    [] c  

[] d    [] e    [] f

[] g    [] h    [] i
```

Expected:

```
[] a    [] d    [] g  

[] b    [] e    [] h

[] c    [] f    [] i
```

Comment: This is not supported in PrimeFaces 0.9.6

Comment: That are 3 columns not 5 .. Anyway you'll probably need to manually reorder the collection behind `<p:selectItems value>` (if that tag exists ..)

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always use the custom layout? And if you are using a primeFaces version that supports ' responsive'  layout for this component, there is a solution that works (but it makes responsiveness harder)

Comment: Oh my  solution also seems to work for the mordern grid layout... I can create an answer for you during the weekedn

Comment: @BalusC Yes it's 3 here i had 5 in my code but i created example of 3. sorry for typo.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you I will be waiting for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily we have CSS to the rescue here. The showcase has a gridlayout example

[image: existing grid layout]

If you take a look at the generate html, you'll see something like

```
<table id="j_idt701:grid" role="presentation" class="ui-selectmanycheckbox ui-widget">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                        <input id="j_idt701:grid:0" name="j_idt701:grid" type="checkbox" value="Miami" data-p-hl="manychkbox" data-p-grouped="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label for="j_idt701:grid:0">Miami</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                        <input id="j_idt701:grid:1" name="j_idt701:grid" type="checkbox" value="London" data-p-hl="manychkbox" data-p-grouped="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label for="j_idt701:grid:1">London</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                        <input id="j_idt701:grid:2" name="j_idt701:grid" type="checkbox" value="Paris" data-p-hl="manychkbox" data-p-grouped="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label for="j_idt701:grid:2">Paris</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Yes, a table is used here but people often forget that you can override the CSS of existing elements with CSS, so you can make the `table`, `tbody`, `tr` and `td` being displayed as 'flex' instead of the default display values. Just use the CSS below to make it do so.

```
table.ui-selectmanycheckbox, table.ui-selectmanycheckbox tbody ,table.ui-selectmanycheckbox tr, table.ui-selectmanycheckbox td{
    display: flex;
}
```

Now the trick is to play with the css `flex-direction` and assign `row` to the `tbody` and `column` to the `tr` like so

```
table.ui-selectmanycheckbox tbody{
    flex-direction: row;
}

table.ui-selectmanycheckbox tr{
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

With the following result:

[image: result after applying flex css]

And if you want it applied for just one select, add an explicit class to the component and use that in the selectors.

Comment: I know this either :D - lets delete this off topic chat